# Different outputs when converting to datetime in data frame lines and column names (Pandas - Python)

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, datetime

Pandas' method "to_datetime" allows us to convert a string into a datetime object. Still, this method seems to have different outputs when converting data frame lines and column labels.

Let df be a data frame with identical date strings in its lines and column labels:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'01-01-2001': ['01-01-2001'], '02-02-2002': ['02-02-2002'],'03-03-2003': ['03-03-2003']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

Now let us convert these data into datetime:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df.loc[0] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[0])
```

[image]

While the column label outputs readable datetime data, the line outputs a different format. Why? And what should be done to obtain readable data in the data frame line?

Comment: because the dtype is already an object,you need to change the dtype of the column , not the row  for it to work

Answer (score 1):

You can use strftime to reformat the date

```
df.loc[0] = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).strftime(date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Output

```
df
Out[400]: 
   2001-01-01  2002-02-02  2003-03-03
0  2001-01-01  2002-02-02  2003-03-03
```